# How can I define the date format mask of the following date format?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a column with the following dates (example):

```
1.5.2018
24.2.2018
6.11.2018
13.10.2018
```

Can the 'DD.MM.YYYY' format handle it if the '0' is missing for the days or months? If not: how can I define the appropriate date format mask?

Comment: What is the type of this column? Is it a varchar2?

Comment: For now nothing. This data is in an excel file. I want to upload it, but before I need to define the date format mask. I want to it will be date format.

Comment: What happened when you tried `to_date('1.5.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy')`?

Comment: I would recommend to use a formula in Excel like `="TO_DATE('"&YEAR(A1)&"-"&MONTH(A1)&"-"&DAY(A1)&"','YYYY-MM-DD')"` Such data you can import without trouble.

Answer (score 3):

From the Oracle documentation on Format Models:

> **FX**
>
> Format exact. This modifier specifies exact matching for the character argument and datetime format model of a `TO_DATE` function:
>
> - Punctuation and quoted text in the character argument must exactly match (except for case) the corresponding parts of the format model.
> - The character argument cannot have extra blanks. Without FX, Oracle ignores extra blanks.
> - Numeric data in the character argument must have the same number of digits as the corresponding element in the format model. Without `FX`, numbers in the character argument can omit leading zeroes.
> - When `FX` is enabled, you can disable this check for leading zeroes by using the `FM` modifier as well.

**Without the `FX` format model**:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( '1.5.2018', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ) AS value FROM DUAL;
```

Will work and outputs (with my `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting):

```
VALUE
--------------------
2018-05-01T00:00:00Z
```

and so will combinations with extra spaces:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( '1 . 5 . 2018', 'DD.MM.YYYY' ) FROM DUAL;
```

**With the `FX` format model**:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( '1.5.2018', 'FXDD.MM.YYYY' ) AS value FROM DUAL;
```

Gives:

```
ORA-01862: the numeric value does not match the length of the format item
```

Specifying the leading zeroes will work:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( '01.05.2018', 'FXDD.MM.YYYY' ) FROM DUAL;

VALUE
--------------------
2018-05-01T00:00:00Z
```

But adding in extra spaces will not:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( '01 . 05. 2018', 'FXDD.MM.YYYY' ) FROM DUAL;

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

**To suppress the check for leading zeroes you can also use the `FM` format model**:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( '1.5.2018', 'FMFXDD.MM.YYYY' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

```
VALUE
--------------------
2018-05-01T00:00:00Z
```

But the statement will not work with extra spaces

```
SELECT TO_DATE( '1.5 .2018', 'FMFXDD.MM.YYYY' ) FROM DUAL;

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
```

Answer (score 1):

The `'DD.MM.YYYY'` format will work. For example:

```
SQL> with yourData(stringDateCol) as (
  2      select '1.5.2018' from dual union all
  3      select '01.05.2018' from dual union all
  4      select '24.2.2018' from dual union all
  5      select '6.11.2018' from dual union all
  6      select '13.10.2018' from dual
  7  )
  8  select to_date( stringDateCol, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
  9  from yourData;

TO_DATE(ST
----------
2018-05-01
2018-05-01
2018-02-24
2018-11-06
2018-10-13

SQL>
```